# Switch 3 keyboard layouts with 2 key combinations

Tags: keyboard-layout

How to do keyboard layout switch like this:

```
 alt + shift | scroll lock | current layout     
-------------+-------------+----------------
      0      |      0      |    colemak
      0      |      1      |    qwerty
      1      |      0      |      ru
      1      |      1      |      ru
```

By 1's and 0's I mean state. Initially state is 0, so If `scroll lock` was pressed it goes to 1,  and if `scroll lock` was pressed again and it goes to 0. Same for alt+shift.

*I'm using xfce4*

Comment: by 1's and 0's, you're implying whether that key combination is being held? (your Question was flagged as "unclear", so some more words might be helpful)

Comment: @JeffSchaller updated the question